# «А ты в тени пальм мой мираж». Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, вставная-конструкция, инверсия

Подскажите, как правильно расставить знаки препинания в данном предложении?
Насколько я понимаю, здесь "в тени пальм" является обстоятельством и относится к "моему миражу", а всё это вместе отождествляется "тебе".
"А ты — в тени пальм мой мираж" — тогда так? Не нужны ли дополнительные знаки из-за своеобразной инверсии?
Или, может, "в тени пальм" — вставная конструкция? "А ты — в тени пальм — мой мираж"? Буду благодарен за разъяснение.

Answer (score 4):

***А ты — в тени пальм мой мираж.***

**1. Грамматика:** Ты — подлежащее, мираж — сказуемое, мой —согласованное определение, в тени пальм — несогласованное обстоятельственное определение.

**2. [Правило Розенталя, пункт 8](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92)**

Если подлежащее выражено **личным местоимением**, а сказуемое — формой именительного падежа **существительного**, тире между ними обычно не ставится: Я честный человек и никогда не говорю комплиментов (Ч.).

Однако тире в этом случае **ставится**: 1) **при логическом подчеркивании**: Я — страница твоему перу.

**3. Интонация:** ***А тЫ** — в тени пальм мой **мирАж.*** Интонационное тире ставится, если подлежащее подчеркнуто логическим ударением, тогда после него в устной речи делается пауза.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

(1) **Вариант оформления** в песне возможен, тогда "в тени пальм"— обособленное уточняющее обстоятельство (там, в тени) или обособленное определение к местоимению "ты". Но там **нужная пауза** между подлежащим и сказуемыми не обозначена, поэтому грамматика выглядит **неопределенной**.

А ты, в тени пальм, мой **мираж**,

*Неизведанный **остров** на отшибе вселенной,*

***Спрячешься**, вот и всё.*

(2) **Я поняла текст так** (если без инверсии):

*А ты — мой **мираж** в тени пальм,*

*Неизведанный **остров** на отшибе вселенной,*

***Спрячешься**, вот и всё.*

**Грамматика:** ты мой мираж, ты неизведанный остров, ты спрячешься. Здесь **однородные сказуемые** к подлежащему "ты".

Comment: Мой мираж - не обращение?

Comment: Мне кажется, что нет: ты мой мираж, ты неизведанный остров, ты спрячешься.

Comment: А ты - в тени пальм, мой мираж:
(как)Неизведанный остров на отшибе вселенной
Спрячешься, - вот и всё.

Comment: Какая, к чёрту, разница - ведь не везёт...
Как призрак в нашей квартире, образ семейной идиллии.

Comment: Смысл такой возможен, но знаков в оригинале нет, чтобы точно его определить.  А вот знаки в вашем варианте очень сложные для такой (футуристической) песни.  Одно тире - это еще куда ни шло.

Answer (score 3):

Как я понимаю, тут целый ряд проблем, есть текст, есть его произнесение, но дело в том, что написание должно отражать понимание, а понимание сложно описуемо, так как поэтический текст.

Нужно ли править грамматику? Или грамматика должна сохранять ошибки и заблуждения в сыром виде?

> Нектарины
> *А ты, в тени пальм, мой мираж
>
> Неизведанный остров на отшибе вселенной
>
> Спрячешься, вот и всё -*
> Какая к чёрту разница, ведь не везёт
> Как призрак в нашей квартире, образ семейной идиллии
> А я искал его в домах с крышами из бугенвиллий
> Как иронично безумие вперемешку с отчаяньем
> Когда, вернувшись назад к тебе, я вновь обещаю, что

Или:

> *А ты, в тени пальм, мой мираж:(? тут не хватает знака, но какого?)
> Неизведанный остров на отшибе вселенной(опять нет знака)
>
> Спрячешься, вот и всё -*(почему тире, если до этого запятая?
> Какая к чёрту разница, ведь не везёт(опять нет знака)
> Как призрак в нашей квартире, образ семейной идиллии(а тут просто запятая)
> А я искал его в домах с крышами из бугенвиллий
> Как иронично безумие вперемешку с отчаяньем
> Когда, вернувшись назад к тебе, я вновь обещаю, что

Я бы ничего не исправлял в этом тексте, кроме "к чёрту" - которое должно обособляться всегда. Как и "чёрт".

**Какая, к чёрту, разница,** - так правильно.

Comment: У них в конце строк нет запятых (обратили внимание?), условная графика, наверное)

Comment: @Sharon Что такое условная графика? Не, ну я в юности тоже писал стихи без знаков в конце строчек. Не знал какой знак поставить, сомневался.

Comment: Это не термин, а моя оценка такой графики)

Comment: По мне же,  графика должна отражать хотя бы какой-то смысл, вполне определенную грамматику и еще – быть красивой! и удобной для прочтения.

Comment: @Sharon зависит от того, для кого/чего пишутся стихи, в стол, или на публику. Публике, конечно, не мешает разъяснить, что к чему. Хотя, обычно, стихи читаются, и это скорее "условная" графика, которая требует произнесения вслух.

Comment: Согласна!  Все должно быть ясным...  Вот только смысл стиха неоднозначен по своей природе, а иначе это уже не стих, а текст)

Comment: @Sharon хотя, как вариант, без знака тоже имеет место быть, когда фраза произносится как коллаж, дробится, когда одно не связывается с другим. Так что это тоже может быть отражено и часто используется в стихах. Синтаксис - это смысловые связки. А в конце строчек строфы все равно пауза идет, интонационная. Такое странное дело, когда форма диктует  смысловое дробление.

Comment: Опять же вы правы... В этом что-то есть.

Comment: @Sharon во многом эта штука потом стала основой "лесенки" Маяковского, которую и Высоцкий использовал, интонационные паузы дробящие фразу, на части, грани образа что ли. И создающие фактуру, объемность.

Comment: Интересно тут у вас! Всем участникам большое спасибо!

Comment: Могу еще добавить, а свидетелей мы потом "уберем"))  В данном случае красота графики и формы – в однородных членах. Называя разные признаки одного предмета, мы раскрываем общую тему, создаем целостный образ, и именно этот повтор важно увидеть и услышать (ты мираж, ты остров, ты спрячешься). При этом форма не должна быть однообразной, чтобы не утомлять читателя. Вот сколько мастерства требуется от поэта. Ну и от редакторов тоже)

Answer (score 2):

Можно и так поставить знаки: *А ты в тени пальм — мой мираж.*

Но не... Не пойдет! Вот оригинал:

> [Нектарины](https://lyrnow.com/1569175)
> *А ты, в тени пальм, мой мираж
>
> Неизведанный остров на отшибе вселенной
>
> Спрячешься, вот и всё -*
> Какая к чёрту разница, ведь не везёт
> Как призрак в нашей квартире, образ семейной идиллии
> А я искал его в домах с крышами из бугенвиллий
> Как иронично безумие вперемешку с отчаяньем
> Когда, вернувшись назад к тебе, я вновь обещаю, что
>
> Там, где солнце не помнит
> И там, где звёзды не знают
> Слышишь, там, где кончается море
> Наша молодость умирает
> Я клянусь тебе, что построю
> Дом, который похож на Титаник
> Там, где солнце уже не помнит
> Там, где звёзды ещё не знают

Расставляем знаки:
*А ты в тени пальм, мой мираж,

Неизведанный остров на отшибе вселенной,

Спрячешься, вот и всё...*

P. S. В следующий раз давайте предложение целиком (или хотя бы ссылку) — а то мы тут все головы поизломаем.